# Counting refferers new members between 2 dates from the same members table

Tags: mysql, count

The project I'm working on right now needs a reference system (currently they have 50K members). I decided to add **ref** and **ref_id** field in members table.

Structure of **members** table;

```
id (int auto),
admin (enum (1,0)),
ref (enum (1,0)),
ref_id (int),
country_id (int),
city_id(int),
town_id(int),
totalRef (int),
fullName (varchar),
registrationDate (datetime)
```

I would like to list referers data which has new members between 2 dates. I wanted to provide a bit more details so I also tried to add country, city, and town in the query. I tried following query but I don't think this is a good approach to go with considering it takes really long time to load ;

```
SELECT m.id, m.fullName, m.country_id, m.city_id, m.town_id, m.totalRef,
(select name from country where country.id = m.country_id) as countryName,
(select name from city where city.id = m.city_id) as cityName,
(select name from town where town.id = m.town_id) as townName,
(select count(id) from members where members.ref_id = m.id AND ref_id > 0 AND registrationDate BETWEEN '2011.11.04 00:00:00' AND '2011.11.04 23:59:59') as newRef

FROM members as m 

WHERE

m.country_id = '224' AND 
m.city_id = '4567' AND
m.town_id = '78964' AND 
m.admin = '0' AND 
m.ref = '1' 

ORDER BY newRef DESC 
LIMIT 0, 25
```

I will be glad if you could help me about this problem. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this -

```
SELECT
  m.id,
  m.fullName,
  m.country_id,
  m.city_id,
  m.town_id,
  m.totalRef,
  cnt.name countryName,
  ct.name cityName,
  t.name townName,
  m2.newRef
FROM members as m 
  LEFT JOIN country cnt
    ON cnt.id = m.country_id
  LEFT JOIN city ct
    ON ct.id = m.city_id
  LEFT JOIN town t
    ON t.id = m.town_id
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT ref_id, COUNT(id) newRef FROM members
      WHERE ref_id > 0 AND registrationDate BETWEEN '2011.11.04 00:00:00' AND '2011.11.04 23:59:59'
      GROUP BY ref_id
    ) m2
    ON m2.ref_id = m.id
WHERE
  m.country_id = '224' AND 
  m.city_id = '4567' AND
  m.town_id = '78964' AND 
  m.admin = '0' AND 
  m.ref = '1' 
ORDER BY
  newRef DESC 
LIMIT
  0, 25;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried it out but there is an error. `LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT COUNT(id) newRef FROM members
      WHERE ref_id > 0 AND registrationDate BETWEEN '2011.11.04 00:00:00' AND '2011.11.04 23:59:59'
      GROUP BY ref_id
    ) m2
    ON m2.ref_id = m.id` on m2.ref_id can't find column. I added `members as r` in front of `m2.ref_id = m.id` and changed it to `r.id = m.ref_id`. Still doesn't work :(

Comment: Yes, of course. The ref_id field should be added to SELECT list. I missed it. I have modified the answer.

Comment: Thank you works like a charm and fast. Added `newRef > 0` and got the results. I didn't want to use `JOINS` at first. I don't know how much bigger those tables will get so I just wanted to avoid using `JOINS` but turns out my query was way a lot worse than `JOINS`. Thank you once again.